# добавления елемента массив? php

Tags: php, массивы

Не могу понять где туплю, есть код который обновляет по API таблицы гуг.

```
$requests = array(); 
$requests[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request(array(
    'updateCells' => array(
     'start' => array(
      'sheetId' => 0, 
      'rowIndex' => $row2, 
      'columnIndex' => 10 
     ), 
     'rows' => array(
      array(
       'values' => array(
        array(
         'userEnteredValue' => array('numberValue' => '111111'), 
         'userEnteredFormat' => array('backgroundColor' => array('red'=>1, 'green'=>1, 'blue'=>0.8)) 
        )
        ) 
      ) 
     ), 
     'fields' => 'userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor' 
    ) 
));
```

проблема в строке 'userEnteredValue' => array('numberValue' => '111111'),

если она в таком виде, все работает, если ставлю вместо единичек переменную
$valid="любой текст";

'userEnteredValue' => array('numberValue' => $valid),

ничего работать не хочет, тоесть получается что массив формируется с ошибкой

Как нормально присвоить этому элементу нужное мне значение?

Comment: Попробуйте к строке преобразовать `'userEnteredValue' => array('numberValue' => $valid + "")`

Comment: Разве numberValue не подразумевает int переменную внутри? Возвращает ли гугл ошибку?

Comment: блин реально тумплю ((( а как тогда туда текст вснуть

Comment: поменял на stringValue, толку ноль

Comment: ```var_dump($valid)``` вас спасет)